# Is this enough to show that this map has constant rank?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, manifolds

My question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177531/retracts-are-submanifolds?answertab=active#tab-top)

I am given a $C^r$ manifold $M$ and a connected subset $A$ of $M$, and a $C^r$retraction $f:M\rightarrow A$ such that $f\vert_A=id:A\rightarrow A$. Then $A$ is a $C^r$ submanifold of $M$.

I know that I need to show that $f$ has constant rank in a neighbourhood $U$ (open in $M$) of $A$ so I can apply the Rank Theorem to finish the proof. I tried the same approach as in [P. W. Michor, Topics in Differential Geometry](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf), section 1.15, but since the hypothesis in this book is kinda different I couldn't use it to get the result I need.

I thought that since $f\vert_A=id:A\rightarrow A$, then for every $x\in A$, $T_xf=Id$ which is surjective. Therefore $f$ is a local submersion in $x$ and so, in a neighbourhood $U_x\underset{open}\subset M$ $f$ has constant rank. Now I can collect all $U_x$ and get an open set $U$ in $M$ where $f$ has constant rank.

Is this correct?

By the way, this is question 2, Section 2 Chapter 1 from Hirsch's "Differential Topology".

Thanks.

Comment: I think you might need to be more careful about the boundary points $x \in A \cap \partial A$.

Comment: Could you be more specific? If $x$ is in this set the $x\in A$.

Comment: Is it immediate that $T_x f =\operatorname{Id}$ in this case? Thinking about it a little more I don't think there's an issue so long as $f$ is $C^r$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $f$ is also $C^r$ as a mapping.

Comment: Maybe I should break it in two cases; the first one being when $A$ is open in $M$ (this is trivial) and the other where $A$ is not open. This is where $\partial A$ comes into play, if $A$ is closed then I guess it's OK (for $Df(x)=Id$ is guaranteed in $\partial A$) but if it's not there might be problems.

Comment: But if $A$ is not closed, if there's a point $X$ in $\partial A$ where $f(x)\neq x$, then there is a neighbourhood of $x$ where $f(y)\neq y$ in this neighbourhood, therefore there would be a point $w$ in $A$ such that $f(w)\neq w$, contradiction. Is this OK?

Comment: Notice that $A$ is exactly the fixed point set of $f:M \to M$. Your argument then works; alternatively just observe that fixed point sets of continuous maps of Hausdorff spaces are closed.

Comment: What's wrong with just quoting Michor's result?  The fact that $f$ is a retraction implies $f\circ f=f$.  Here's the problem with your approach: If you are considering $f$ as a map from $M$ to $A$, then $T_xf$ does not make sense, because $A$ is not yet known to be a manifold.  On the other hand, if you consider $f$ as a map from $M$ to $M$ (whose image happens to be $A$), then it's not generally true that $T_xf = \operatorname{Id}$, because $f$ will not generally be equal to the identity on an open set.

Comment: @JackLee I see the problem in my approach now. Thanks! I'll try to use the same argument as Michor, since $f\circ f=f$ in $M$.